# How to fix "Could not handle the request" on google functions node js

Tags: node.js, ajax, google-cloud-platform, request, google-cloud-datastore

So.. I have a problem here, I've created multiple functions. My objective is to call them using simple AJAX requests. 
For example:

```
function createPost(title,description,category,subcategory,tags){
let data = {"kind":"Posts","key":""+title+"","value":{"category":""+category+"","description":""+description+"","subcategory":""+subcategory+"",
"tags":"{'tags' : [{'name':'Lince','color':'blue'},{'name':'BUG','color':'orange'}]}"}};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://"+REGION+"-"+PROJECT_ID+".cloudfunctions.net/"+DATASTORE_CREATE_POST+"",
    data: JSON.stringify(data), 
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
    },
});}
```

I have this function to save a new Kind key:

```
exports.set = (req, res) => {
//SET CORS
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*')
// The value contains a JSON document representing the entity we want to save
if (!req.body.value) {
  throw new Error(
    'Value not provided. Make sure you have a "value" property in your request'
  );}
const key = getKeyFromRequestData(req.body);
  const entity = {
    key: key,
    data: req.body.value,
  };

  return datastore
    .save(entity)
    .then(() => res.status(200).send(`Entity ${key.path.join('/')} saved.`))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};
```

If a test this function on google site, the result is OK:
[image]

But, If I want to call the same function on AJAX request like I said before.. I get:

> Error: could not handle the request

Comment: What happens if you try and send the request using Postman ... (or equivalent tool) ... https://www.getpostman.com/   ... What I'm curious to see is if the puzzle can be narrowed to how the REST call is being made vs how the REST call is being processed?   Assuming the request is getting to GCP, I'd also be curious to see any logs written to Stackdriver.

Comment: I get "Error: could not handle the request" using Postman

Comment: https://imgur.com/kBz2b9B take a look here -> logs

Comment: The stackdriver log is very useful ... and seems to show the exact line number in your source (index.js) where the error is being detected.  However, in your post of the source we can't tell which line that relates to.  Can you update your original post with your new stack driver discoveries and indicate the line that is throwing the exception as reported by stackdriver?